# Как выполнить действие после отрисовки Activity (fragment)

Tags: java, android, android-view

Есть ли метод с которого возможно воздействовать на только что отобразившуюся активность? Мне надо перезапустить view, как только она отрисуется. А отрисовать надо, чтобы узнать ее размер. После чего сразу выполнить другое действие с этими данными.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К примеру у вас есть `View mExampleView` повесьте на нее обсервер, он сработает, как только вьюшка будет нарисована на экране. Когда будет вызван `onGlobalLayout`, вы можете узнать ее размер, затем отпишитесь и выполняйте нужный код.

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = mExampleView.getViewTreeObserver();
viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
  @Override
  public void onGlobalLayout() {
    mEaxampleView.getHeight(); // будет больше 0
    mEaxampleView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    // Остальные действия
  }
});
```

Comment: Странно `View.post(new Runnable()` не сработал. А ваш пример работает. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Мне помогает такой код:

```
 myView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ...нужные действия           
        }
 },100);
```

на `post` `View` уже отрисовано.

UPD: изменил `post` на `postDelayed` - так должно работать

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего вас устроит метод `onResume()`. Он есть и в активити и во фрагменте.

Comment: `onResume()` не подходит. В этом методе `view.getHeight` все еще = 0; Надо что-то среднее межу `onResume()` и `onPause()`